# Is this a real photo or an art work?

Tags: nebula

I've never seen this Hubble picture, is it an artist impression? It's fascinating because there are voids apparently cause by supernovae.

[image]
<sup>From the video [1 Hour of Epic Space Music: COSMOS - Volume 1](https://youtu.be/41Y6xov0ppw?t=1708)</sup>

The deviant art mentioned in the information below the video is by Natasha Sharma, she has a different style than that. There are also real photos from hubble in the video, I can't tell if it is a genius space artist or a real photo.

Comment: Well, it does look artificial to me, just by the sheer amount of detail in the image, especially when you look at the 720p resolution image. Also the central brightness looks way too oversaturated for my eye, and that's not an image that any respectable astronomical institution would put out there. But then again, I don't know all the nebula images.

Comment: There are a lot of image links below the video. Did you check them all?

Comment: The star is too large for the nebula.   Nebulae are enormous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ['From Nothing'](https://rhads.deviantart.com/art/From-Nothing-492031701), made by [cosmicspark](https://cosmicspark.deviantart.com/), a.k.a Tim Barton.

> This picture was painted from nothing, in roughly 12 hours while I listened to a lot of interesting lectures on physics, including Dr. Lawrence Krauss' famous lecture "A Universe From Nothing".